# What is the actual advantage of using React Context in MobX?

Tags: react-hooks, mobx-react

I'm migrating a React Native app that was using MobX provider/inject pattern. My new root component looks something like this:

```
export const ShellComponent = observer(() => {

    const {isInitialized, navigationStore} = useStores();

    if (!isInitialized) {
        return (
            <SplashPage />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <StartPage />
        );
    }
});
```

So far, so good. As soon as the `isInitalized` flag in my store changes, the component re-renders.

However, I have a lot of legacy component classes in there, and there I can't use hooks. So my store setup also contains a `getRootStore()` function that returns the raw root store rather than a React Context:

```
// single root store instance
const rootStoreInstance: RootStore = new RootStore();

// expose the store
export const getRootStore = () => rootStoreInstance;

// Root store wrapped in a React context.
const rootStoreContext: React.Context<RootStore> = React.createContext<RootStore>(rootStoreInstance);

// Root store hook
export const useStores = () => React.useContext(rootStoreContext);
```

So in my component class, I can now invoke `getRootStore` function and everything works, too.
However: I can just as well use `getRootStore` in my functional component. So just exchanging `useStores` with `getRootStore` in the first snippet works just the same. Which begs the question: What am I overlooking that justifies the distinctions and overhead of the React Context here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (or at least it will be very hard and hacky) have server side rendering when using `singleton` or `instance` pattern, because you want new `store` for every render.

Also it is probably a bit harder to test stuff because you can't just switch your root store without dependency mock, but with `Provider` and `Context` you can use dependency injection.

But overall, if you don't have `SSR` (well in RN you surely don't) or don't have such tests, which needs store to be mocked, then this pattern is totally fine.